# Set multi line error in struct array

Tags: c++, c, struct

I want to create a modules system in C++. Following is my program, which there are no issues with.

```
void First_Modules()
{
    // Anything ...
}

void Second_Modules()
{
    // Anything ...
}


typedef void(*Func) ();

struct All_Modules
{
    char *Name;
    Func This_Function;
};

struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules }, {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules }};
```

My problem is that I want to send the modules information to Load_All_Functions without using

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules }, {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules }};
```

I want something like this:

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules }};

struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules }};
```

(split each set process). but when I try to run this, I see this error
 `'Loads': redefinition; different basic types`

What should I do? I don't want to use

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules }, {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules }};
```

and I want to set each full separate like

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules }};

struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions[] = { {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules }};
```

What should i do? I want to have each modules function name and load it every where in the program.

Comment: The question is phrased in a very hard-to-read and "unwelcoming" manner. Organize your thoughts, then the question, if you're hoping to get a proper answer.

Comment: What is the underlying problem? That you don't want to have everything on one line, that you don't want to do everything at once, or that you don't know the number of functions in advance? Or something else?

Comment: Is the goal to have more than one module loaded at a time?

Comment: some thing like that ..... i want to have each modules function name and load it every where in the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is no need to declare an array of the structures

If the program is written in C then try the following

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions;

Load_All_Functions = ( struct All_Modules ){"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules };

Load_All_Functions = ( struct All_Modules ){"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules };
```

In C++ you can write

```
struct All_Modules Load_All_Functions;

Load_All_Functions = {"Load_Modules_1", First_Modules };

Load_All_Functions = {"Load_Modules_2", Second_Modules };
```

Take into account that in C++ data member `name` must be declared like

```
const char *Name;
```

if you are going to use string literals as initializers.

Comment: redefinition; multiple initialization

Comment: @user216085 Did you use C++ or C code? For example C++ code compiles successfully.

Comment: @user216085 Copy and paste what I wrote.

Comment: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Comment: @user216085  Are you unable to copy and paste code?